# Look-up through multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, lookup-tables

I have 4 tables. R, T, RT_imp and RT.

```
Table R (R_key, R_id)
Table T (T_key, T_id)
Table RT_imp (R_id, T_id, A,B,C)
```

Using these 3 tables I need to populate 4th table RT.

```
Table RT (R_key, T_key, A,B,C)
```

I need to find corresponding keys to ids.
(R_key from R  related to R_id of RT_imp, T_key from T related to T_id of RT_imp to insert into RT along with A,B,C)

I need to do this in a stored procedure. How do I do these?

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem?  Where are you stuck?  And what **exactly** do you mean by *populate*? Do you need to truncate it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  I created temp tables and aliases, but you could replace them with your table names.

```
Declare @R table (R_Key int, R_id int)
Declare @T table (T_Key int, T_id int)
Declare @RT_imp table (R_id int, T_id int, A char(1), B char(1), C char(1))
Declare @RT table (R_Key int, T_Key int, A char(1), B char(1), C char(1))

insert into @RT
    select r.R_Key
    , T_Key
    , rtimp.A
    , rtimp.B
    , rtimp.C
    from @RT_imp rtimp
    inner join @R r on r.R_id = rtimp.R_id
    inner join @T t on t.T_id = rtimp.T_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure insertdata
Declare @R table (R_Key int, R_id int)
Declare @T table (T_Key int, T_id int)
Declare @RT_imp table (R_id int, T_id int, A char(1), B char(1), C char(1))
Declare @RT table (R_Key int, T_Key int, A char(1), B char(1), C char(1))
AS
BEGIN
insert into @RT
    select r.R_Key, t.T_Key, rtimp.A, rtimp.B, rtimp.C
    from @RT_imp rtimp, @R r, @T t
where r.R_id = rtimp.R_id
and t.T_id = rtimp.T_id

END
```